# How can i scroll to each section inside a overflow container with click of a button?

Tags: javascript, scroll, gsap

I have a container that has some sections inside, and it scrolls using the user's scroll value. I want to scroll to each section with the click of a button.

I tried to use the scrollIntoView() function, but that didn't work for me because I am using gsap for trigger position and I also have some other animation linked with it, so if I use scrollIntoView(), my other animation won't work. So, I would need to scroll the window to make the animations work. I tried a lot of things like overighting the progress of scrollTrigger, using offsetTop value of the container and adding the height of the section but couldn't figure out something that worked. If someone can help, I would appreciate it.

Here's a little demo of what i've been trying:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".texts");
const wrappper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

const scrollToElement = (index) => {
  let totalOffset = wrappper.offsetTop;

  for (let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    totalOffset += slides[i].offsetHeight / 3;
    console.log(i);
  }

  const scrollOff = totalOffset;
  console.log(scrollOff);

  window.scrollTo({
    top: scrollOff,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
};

buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    scrollToElement(index);
  });
});

ScrollTrigger.create({
  trigger: container,
  start: "top top",
  end: "bottom top",
  pin: true,
  scrub: 0.1,
  markers: true,
  onUpdate: (self) => {
    const progress = self.progress;

    animationProgress = progress;

    const scrollPosition =
      progress * (content.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight);
    content.scrollTop = scrollPosition;
  }
});
```